# Why is my nginx routing my react app static files to my index.html

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I want to host a demo app on a subroute of my domain. When I place the app in the root of the domain and use the following configuration, it works:

```
server {
   server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
   root /var/www/my-app/build;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
       try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }
}
```

But when i move it to a subroute using the following configuration, it correctly fetches the initial index.html but then routes the static file requests (for css, js, images...) to index.html as well.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
        }
        location /demo-apps/my-app{
                root /var/www/my-app/build;
                try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
}
```

And I don't understand why. Here's a screen capture of the request which succeeds but returns the index.html file instad of the js file:

[image]

And here's the folder structure on the server:

[image]

As I understand it, the request from the first screen capture should match the $uri condition in the second location block and return the corresponding js file but, clearly, I'm wrong. What do I need to change for this to work?

Before anyone asks, yes, I did restart nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the file is constructed by concatenating the value of `root` with the value of `$uri`. So a request for `/demo-apps/my-app/css/foo.css` will be looked for at `/var/www/my-app/build/demo-apps/my-app/css/foo.css`, which is the wrong place.

You can use `alias` instead (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)), for example:

```
location /demo-apps/my-app {
    alias /var/www/my-app/build;
    try_files $uri /demo-apps/my-app/index.html;
}
```

*However, using `alias` and `try_files` together can be problematic. See [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).*

---

Or use a regular expression `location` (see [this dcoument](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)) to extract the latter part of the URI, for example:

```
location ~ ^/demo-apps/my-app(/.*)?$ {
    root /var/www/my-app/build;
    try_files $1 /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Thank, this works for me. I guess I just assumed that the part of the URI *after* the location part is what's appended to the root.